# Python OpenCV Threading Event for MouseClick Location in Image

Tags: python, opencv, python-multithreading

I am struggling with my code to get it working!
The drawing is working, only the threading does not.

I would like to check some points from the image and store it in the global variable points. So every mouse click should fire an event set to continue to the next point to choose.

When I first call the thread the thread starts and I can
create some circles in the image, but not as I would like it to work.
The program get stuck in the threading and I can only stop it with the esc key.

Even the first print Message does not pop up.

I would really appreciate your answers!! 
The program runs without the e.wait(). So i tried checking all points I would like to have and then go with the esc key to get back to the other function, but that is not the way threading should work? and I would like it to run as described if it is possible :)

Thanks a lot!
Hannes

```
import cv2
import cv
import time
import numpy as np
from threading import Thread
from threading import Event
import sys

points = []
e = Event()
key = Event()
winName3 = "hsv image colors?"
imCalRGB = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
calibrationComplete = False


def calibrate():

    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    global imCalRGB
    imCalRGB = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)

    global calibrationComplete
    global e
    global key
    e = Event()
    key = Event()
    calibrationComplete = False

    while calibrationComplete == False:

        cv2.namedWindow(winName3, cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
        cv2.imshow(winName3, imCalRGB)
        t = Thread(CalibrationWindowThread(imCalRGB), "Get Points")
        t.start()
        time.sleep(4)
        print "Please select the center of the 20 points outermost rim."
        e.wait()
        e.clear()

        cv2.circle(imCalRGB, points[0], 3,(255, 0, 0),2, 8)
        cv2.imshow(winName3, imCalRGB)

        print "Please select the center of the 3 points outermost rim."
        e.wait()
        e.clear()

        cv2.circle(imCalRGB, points[1], 3,(255, 0, 0),2, 8)
        cv2.imshow(winName3, imCalRGB)

        print "Please select the center of the 11 points outermost rim."
        e.wait()
        e.clear()

        cv2.circle(imCalRGB, points[2], 3,(255, 0, 0),2, 8)
        cv2.imshow(winName3, imCalRGB)

        print "Please select the center of the 6 points outermost rim."
        e.wait()
        e.clear()

        cv2.circle(imCalRGB, points[3], 3,(255, 0, 0),2, 8)
        cv2.imshow(winName3, imCalRGB)

        height, width = imCalRGB.shape[:2]


        ...

def CalibrationWindowThread(im):

    cv2.imshow(winName3, im)
    cv2.setMouseCallback(winName3, on_mouse)

    global key

    while True:
        if not key.is_set():
            test = cv2.waitKey(1)
            if test == 27:
                #cv2.destroyWindow(winName3)
                break
        else:
            break


def on_mouse(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        #events
        global points
        global e

        #append user clicked points
        points.append((x, y))
        e.set()
        print points
        cv2.circle(imCalRGB, (x, y), 3,(255, 0, 0),2, 8)
        cv2.imshow(winName3, imCalRGB)
        #key.set()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Welcome to darts!"
    calibrate()][1]
```